# Wrong legend after DWG import in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend, import, display, dwg

I successfully imported DWG file into QGIS (3.22.11) and all vector features are displayed correctly, but only on the map.

In the *Layer* docking window all lines are black and polygons are blue.
In some ways, vector objects do not display symbology in that window, although the relevant fields from the attribute table are used (see picture attached).

[image]

The same applies to objects in the *Legend* field, included in the *Print Layout*. But here it seems that the corresponding attribute table is not linked at all.

[image]

Comment: Did you use this method to import the dwg?  https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=dwg#importing-a-dxf-or-dwg-file.  If that didn't preserve all or much of the symbology you can use the standard categorized symbology QGIS provides and set the symbology yourself and save it as a style file for future use.

Answer (score 0):

In the symbology window, on the right of each parameter, you can enter the corresponding field of your attribute table as shown in the image.

[image: chosing field with visualisation attribute]

Comment: These fields are used, otherwise they would not be visible with different styling on the map. The problem is that Lines/Polygons are displayed without that styling in _Layer_ docking window, which subsequently leads to the lack of styling in the _Legend_ included in the _Print Layout_.